# How to use React in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, reactjs

I have a Django application in which a view displays booking data of all the theaters for a particular date. After the data is loaded, an authorized user can perform various actions like assign coordinator, change timings etc. Each of these actions are performed using ajax (jquery) and the UI is updated after the ajax response is complete. The code has become very complex. I wish to use React. Can I use React after the page is loaded? Or Do I have to just load an empty page and then get data, and then initialize the page with React components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can use React partially on your page after page load in this way – `React.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#yourcontainer');` – in this case you'll bootstrap some small component to a specific container